# PIL (Pillow) not working for Python 3.8 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library

This is how I installed Pillow via the Terminal: `pip install Pillow`

I am running **Python 3.8.3**.
When I tried to `import PIL` this showed up: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

Comment: This can be due to multiple python installations. Do you have other instances of python installed on your machine ? Maybe the pip you are using points to a different instance of python.

Comment: What's the output when you run `python --version`?

Comment: If it's not 3.8.3, then most likely Sushruth is right

Comment: As there are a zillion ways to install python3.8 on your mac and some of them have side-effects on how to use pip (or pip3) with or without a virtual env : a bit more info on your python install would be handy. The output of `which pip` and `which pip3` and `which python3` can contain hints why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you should check if you python3.8.3 is the default.

E.g. what happens when you run `python3 --version`

When that show the correct python version I would create a virtual env (aka "venv") first: this ensures that you don't pollute your new python with global packages.

`python3 -m venv my_venv`

Then activate the venv:

`source my_venv/bin/activate`

Now you are ready to PIP install the dep:

`pip3 install Pillow`

Comment: Kewl. I think it would add value to the question if you could provide a bit more info regarding which python3.8.3 you are running (e.g. how did you install it)

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install Pillow==2.2.1
```

Use above command to install Pillow and import by bellow statement

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: This actually throws an error on my computer, but works without specifying the version

Comment: on OSX the "pip" could still point to the system python, depending on how python was installed.